# Wordpress Plugin for sorting members based on location

Tags: wordpress, geolocation, wordpress-theming

I am currently developing a website where I need members to be sorted into groups based on location. What can I use to automatically do this. I want the members of the groups to be sorted based on their distance from a college campus, meaning that only people who are, let's say, 2.5 miles radius of the middle of a campus to be in this group.

Comment: What have you done so far that is not working?

Comment: you need a dataabase, then to query the database based on those parameters. Without more information, there's nothing else we can do